# ¿como cambiar el atributo d de path de svg o alguna posible alterntiva, para que se adapte al ancho de mi web?

Tags: html, css, svg

me pregunto si esto es posible ya que tengo un svg que adapto a la pantalla de mi página web,el problema es que cuando quiero usar el svg para pantallas mas grandes aumenta su tamaño de tal forma para poder estirarlo y que ajuste al ancho que acaba siendo demasiado grande y ocupa media pantalla.

Este es el svg inicial si vamos cambiando el tamaño de la pantalla no se ajusta correctamente al borde derecho en ciertos momentos para ello he intentado que se vea bien en moviles, si le añadimos al css la opcion para tablets tambien sigue adaptandose correctamente, pero cuando cambiamos a tamaño a escritorio, hay que ajustar el ancho nuevamente y el svg ocupa media pantalla y esto no es lo que yo estoy buscando, ya que lo quiero usar de cabecera.

```css
@media (min-width: 481px) {    
 svg{
     width: 114%;
     }
}
```

```html
<svg  viewBox="0 0 500 500">
   <path d="M0, 100 C150, 200 350,0 500, 100 L500, 00 L0, 0 Z" style="stroke:none; fill:black;">
   </path>
</svg>
```

Para ello he modificado un poco el svg para que en pantallas de escritorio quede correctamente bien, pero ahora no se como hacer el cambio, o como adaptarlo de forma diferente para que quede correctamente en cada tipo de pantalla.

```css
@media (min-width: 1025px) {
    svg{
                width: 125%;
        }
    
  }
```

```html
<svg  viewBox="0 0 500 500">
 <path d="M0, 44 C210, 90 291,1 565, 70 L500, 00 L0, 0 Z" style="stroke:none;fill:black;">
  </path>
</svg>
```

Como puedo hacer el cambio, para que se ajuste adecuadamente? hay alguna forma de cambiar la opcion d='M0, 100 C150, 200 350,0 500, 100 L500, 00 L0, 0 Z'  por d="M0, 44 C210, 90 291,1 565, 70 L500, 00 L0, 0 Z" ??

o hay alguna alterntiva para hacer que se adapte de forma adecuada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero que he entendi correctamente tu pregunta:

1. El viewBox del svg es demasiado grande. Para que se ajuste al path que tienes voy a utilizar el método [getBBox()](http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/svg/algunos-metodos-js-en-svg.php) y voy a utilizar los valores de la caja delimitadora del path para crear el valor del viewBox.
2. Si lo que quieres es estirar el svg puedes dar al svg el tamaño que tu quieres por ejemplo `svg{width:100vw; height:200px;}` o sea tan ancho como la pantalla pero solo 200px de alto. También voy a utilizar El atributo [preserveAspectRatio = "none"](http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/svg/preserveaspectratio.php) que dice al svg que no tiene que mantener las proporciones.

Asimismo no olvides utilizar un css reset para eliminar márgenes y paddings indeseados.

```js
//console.log(elPath.getBBox())
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
svg{width:100vw; height:130px;}
```

```html
<svg  viewBox="0 0 500 130" preserveAspectRatio ="none">
   <path id="elPath" d="M0, 100 C150, 200 350,0 500, 100 L500, 00 L0, 0 Z" style="stroke:none; fill:black;">
   </path>
</svg>
```

Si sigues queriendo cambiar el valor del atributo d lo mas sencillo sería utilizar 2 elementos path. En el css puedes hacer algo así:

```
#a{display:block}
#b{display:none}
@media (max-width:480px) {
  #a{display:none}
  #b{display:block}
}
```

donde #a y #b son los dos paths

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!!! me ha servido perfecto desconocia esto, lo guardo como oro :)